# ICS URL outputting 5 hours behind

Tags: php, wordpress, strtotime, icalendar

I'll start off by saying that I am not a PHP developer. So I had another developer create a plugin that takes the start and end time from the Wordpress plugin CalendarizeIt and outputs that into a formatted ICS url. The problem is that the url is outputting a start and end time 5 hours earlier than it should.

Here's the plugin PHP:

```
<?php
// Original script from http://jamiebicknell.tumblr.com/post/413492676/ics-generator-php-class#_=_
// Modified by Sean Carruthers

$start          = $_GET['start'];
$end            = $_GET['end'];
$name           = $_GET['name'];
$description    = $_GET['description'];
$location       = $_GET['location'];
$uid            = "kaneko" . strtotime("now");

$data = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTART:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",$start)."\r\nDTEND:".date("Ymd\THis\Z",$end)."\r\nLOCATION:".$location."\r\nTRANSP: OPAQUE\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nUID:".$uid."\r\nDTSTAMP:".date("Ymd\THis\Z")."\r\nSUMMARY:".$name."\r\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\r\nPRIORITY:1\r\nCLASS:PUBLIC\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR";

header("Content-type:text/calendar; charset=utf-8");
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'.ics"');
echo $data;
?>
```

Then in the Wordpress theme file:

```
<?php

$start_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, "fc_start", true);
$c_start_date = date("M j, Y",strtotime($start_date));

$end_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, "fc_end", true);
$c_end_date = date("M j, Y",strtotime($end_date));

$start_time = get_post_meta($post->ID, "fc_start_time", true);
$end_time = get_post_meta($post->ID, "fc_end_time", true);

$ics_args['start'] = strtotime($start_date . " " . $start_time);
$ics_args['end'] = strtotime($end_date . " " . $end_time);

$ics_args['name'] = get_the_title();
$ics_args['description'] = get_the_content();

$ics_args['location'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, "location", true);

$ics_url = plugins_url('kaneko/calendarize-it-mods/ics_event.php') . "?";
foreach($ics_args as $key => $value) {
   $ics_url .= "$key=$value&";
}

if($c_start_date == $c_end_date) {
   echo $c_start_date;
} else {
   echo $c_start_date . " - <br />" . $c_end_date;
}

?>
```

And finally the `$ics_url` variable is getting echoed in an anchor tag like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo $ics_url; ?>">
```

I've tried changing the strtotime in the `$uid` variable of the plugin to something like `+5 hours` but it does not seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Oh and I also played around with changing the timezone in the Wordpress settings. It is currently set to UTC-5, so I thought changing it to like Chicago would help but it did not either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line below add `X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York`

> $data = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\r\nX-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York\r\n

UPDATE: i have updated the whole line of code, its using `DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:` with out the `Z` and the same for `DTEND`

```
$data = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\nVERSION:2.0\r\nMETHOD:PUBLISH\r\nX-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York\r\nBEGIN:VEVENT\r\nDTSTART;VALUE=DATE:".date("Ymd\THis",$start)."\r\nDTEND;VALUE=DATE:".date("Ymd\THis",$end)."\r\nLOCATION:".$location."\r\nTRANSP: OPAQUE\r\nSEQUENCE:0\r\nUID:".$uid."\r\nDTSTAMP:".date("Ymd\THis\Z")."\r\nSUMMARY:".$name."\r\nDESCRIPTION:".$description."\r\nPRIORITY:1\r\nCLASS:PUBLIC\r\nEND:VEVENT\r\nEND:VCALENDAR";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That didn't seem to be working though.

Comment: can you supply us with the output from your feed?

Comment: Sure thing: ```http://thekaneko.org/wp-content/plugins/kaneko/calendarize-it-mods/ics_event.php?start=1376388000&end=1376409600&name=The%20Millennial%20Trains%20Project&description=&location=KANEKO%20|%201111%20Jones%20St&```

Comment: I have updated the answer above try the new line I have given you